# Proving inequality of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to prove the simple inequality that $P(A<B)  \geq P(A< c)\times P(B > c)$ where both $A$ and $B$ are random variables and $c$ is a constant.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Not true. Consider $\Omega=[0,1]$, $A(\omega)=\omega$, $B(\omega)=\omega-\frac12$ and $c=\frac14$.

Comment: You mean the inequality does not hold ?

Comment: Yes, I do.${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming $A, B$ to be independent? If not, if $A=B$ then $P(A<B)=0$ but $P(A<c),P(B>c)>0$ for for $c$. So, I will assume they are independent, discrete (for simplicity).

$P(A<B) = \sum_i P(B=i)P(A \leq i) $ then  $P(A<B) \geq \sum_{i\geq c} P(B=i)P(A \leq i) $ for any choice of $c$.

Since $P(A \leq i) \geq P(A \leq c)$ for all $i\geq c$,
$P(A<B) \geq \sum_{i\geq c} P(B=i)P(A \leq i) \geq \sum_{i\geq c} P(B=i)P(A\leq c) 
 = P(B\geq c)P(A\leq c)$.

This is true for all $c$ if $A, B$ are independent. You can produce counterexamples if they are dependent.

Comment: I don't understand why P(A<= i) >= P(A<= c) , since we have no information about c

Comment: Because we are assuming $i \geq c$ and $\{ A \leq c\} \subset \{A \leq i \}$